# Unable to create web app bot in azure with bot framework 4.2

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

Few months back I have created a web app bot and downloaded Basic Bot source code from my Azure portal. It was written in Microsoft Bot framework 4.2.1

I was trying to publish the same code into another Azure environment. But I am facing compatibility issues. This time when I created the Web app bot in new Azure environment, the source code is in 4.3 where the folder structure is different from that of what I had downloaded earlier.

So, I actually want to create a Web App Bot (v 4.2.1) in Microsoft Azure. But the template for web app bot is having the newer version, 4.3.  Is there a way I create the web app bot with older version, say 4.2. Is it possible ?

I have read the migrating procedure but still it did not work for me. How to fix this compatibility issue?

Comment: You can actually deploy the bot (v 4.2.1), it should not be a problem. Can you tell me the exact error you are facing. By the way are you able to run your bot in emulator?

Comment: Can you share what's different about the folder structure?